# Up Navigation - transition does not slide from right to left

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-xml

I've created some custom transitions so when a button is clicked the pages slide in and out. This works perfectly for when a page is entered (slides from left to right) and when the back button is clicked (slides from right to left) but when the "up" button is clicked in the action bar, the page slides from left to right when I want it to behave like pressing the back button. Here's is the code I am using in the styles.xml file:

```
<style name="YourAnimation.Activity" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity"> 
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_left</item> 
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_right</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_right</item>     
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_left</item> 
</style>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `overridePendingTransition()` but you'd have to insert it everytime you switch activities.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enterAnim, R.anim.exitAnim);
        return true;
...
```

You'd also might want to check how you implement `onClick()` for the up-button. Here I'm calling `super.onBackPressed()` which calls `finish()` on the activity.

Comment: By doing this, you are making the up navigation button function exactly like the back button.  I think this is the wrong behavior because the up navigation should transition to the top of the Task where as the back navigation just pop the existing activity off the stack.